# Get index of select option in an optgroup with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following select:

```
<select name="end" id="end"> 
    <optgroup label="Morning"> 
        <option value="12:00a">12:00 am</option> 
        <option value="12:30a">12:30 am</option> 
        <option value="1:00a">1:00 am</option> 
        <option value="1:30a">1:30 am</option> 
    </optgroup> 
    <optgroup label="Evening"> 
        <option value="12:00p">12:00 pm</option> 
        <option value="12:30p">12:30 pm</option> 
        <option value="1:00p" selected="selected">1:00 pm</option> 
        <option value="1:30p">1:30 pm</option> 
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

I need to find the **overall** index of the selected option, but the optgroup is making that difficult.  In other words, the selected one should return 6, but it is returning 2.  I tried this:

```
var idx = $('#end :selected').prevAll().size();
```

But that returns the index within that optgroup, not the overall index.  I can't change the format or values of the select options.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Erm... whyever not good old DOM methods? For a single-select:

```
var idx= document.getElementById('end').selectedIndex;

// or $('#end')[0].selectedIndex if you must
```

Or, which will also work on multi-selects, get the `option` element node you're interested in and fetch [option.index](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-14038413) on it.

This is massively faster and simpler than getting jQuery to process complex selectors.

Comment: Heh, *exactly*. Cripes, I'm just gonna go ahead and remove the "javascript" tag from this show of DOM ignorance.

Comment: But will this work with the optgroup? I should test it I suppose.

Comment: Yes, `selectedIndex` will be `6`, as stated in the question.

Comment: Yes indeed it does work. Much more efficient than the jquery way! I'm switching the answer to this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Cresent - I just added back the javascript tag. Since I've now chosen a javascript answer, it seemed appropriate to do.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function to find an element within a set. Construct a set of all the options using `$("#end option")`. Find the selected option using the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) pseudo-element. **Note:** indexes are 0-based.

```
var options = $("#end option");
var idx = options.index(options.filter(":selected"));
```

Comment: oh that's good to know.  (oo that's a new 1.4 thing; I can't wait to upgrade.)

Comment: @Pointy: nothing there requires jQuery 1.4. I've linked to those docs but as far as I can tell, this will work in any version.

Comment: @cletuus Oh OK then; I was going by what it says in the jQuery API docs for "index(selector)" - "version added: 1.4"

Comment: @Pointy: yes thats new but I'm using `index(element)` which is "since 1.0".

Comment: @cletus, thanks again for your solution, it is certainly a great jquery-only way to do this. But I'm switching my choice to the answer given by @bobince as it is far more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this:

```
$('#end option:selected').prop('index')
```

This worked for me. The `attr('selectedIndex')` only brought up undefined with the select list.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing in jquery way is also short and simple:

```
var idx = $('#end').attr('selectedIndex');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//funcion para seleccionar con jquery por el index del select 
var text = '';
var canal = ($("#name_canal").val()).split(' ');
$('#id_empresa option').each(function(i, option) {
        text = $('#id_empresa option:eq('+i+')').text();
        if(text.toLowerCase() == canal[0].toLowerCase()){
            $('#id_empresa option:eq('+i+')').attr('selected', true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = -1;
$('#end option').each(function(i, option) {
  if (option.selected) index = i;
});
```

A little ugly but I think that'd work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem returning all selected option's index value .
you can try following code , may be help you.

code:

javascript code:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">
```

```
       $(function(){

                $('#allcheck').click(function(){
                var chk=$('#select_option >optgroup > option:selected');
                   chk.each(function(){
                       alert('Index: ' + $('option').index(this));
                });
            });
   });});
```

HtML CODE:

```
       <select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="select_option" name="option_value[]">
         <optgroup label="Morning"> 
            <option value="12:00a">12:00 am</option> 
            <option value="12:30a">12:30 am</option> 
            <option value="1:00a">1:00 am</option> 
            <option value="1:30a">1:30 am</option> 
        </optgroup> 
        <optgroup label="Evening"> 
           <option value="12:00p">12:00 pm</option> 
           <option value="12:30p">12:30 pm</option> 
           <option value="1:00p" selected="selected">1:00 pm</option> 
           <option value="1:30p">1:30 pm</option> 
    </optgroup>
```

```
     <strong>Select&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="cursor:pointer;" id="allcheck">All</a>
 </strong>
```