# How to select an option with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, xpath, html-select, casperjs

I try to set select option attribute to selected. But I try to avoid using nth-child in CasperJS because there are bugs in PhantomJS's nth-child.
So I try to use this as the subtitution of jQuery(css_path).

```js
function setSelectedCountry(i){
    window.__utils__.echo("i :"+i);
    var query = "//*[@id='cboCountry']/optgroup[2]/option["+i+"]";
    __utils__.getElementByXPath(query).setAttribute("selected","selected");
}
```

But, when I evaluate that code by this way

```js
this.evaluate(setSelectedCountry, 5);
```

The select option is not changed.

Moreover, when I try to trigger `onblur()` using

```js
document.getElementById("cboCountry").onblur();
```

inside `setSelectedCountry()` funtion, there were nothing happened.

Why this happened?

Also, when I try to call the function with XPath expression, and the other one is using CSS selector, I got undefined error returned from CasperJS.

I use this function :

```js
function getCityName(i){
    var query = "//*[@id='cboCity']/option["+i+"]";
    return __utils__.getElementByXPath(query).innerText;
}
```

then I got the other one:

```js
function setSelectedCountry(i){
    var query = "#cboCountry > optgroup:nth-child(3) > option:nth-child("+i+")";
    jQuery(query).attr("selected", "selected").blur();
}
```

When I try to run both of them, then this is what I've got

```js
PAGE.ERROR: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
'__utils__.getElementByXPath(query).innerText')
```

Can you give me suggestions?

[EDITED]

Here is my markup :
This one for cboCountry select option :

```html
<select name="cboCountry" id="cboCountry" onkeypress="return selectItem();" onkeyup="event.cancelbubble=true;return false;" onkeydown="return handleKey();" onfocus="activeList=this;this.enteredText='';" onchange="//hs.DropCity();" onblur="hs.DropCity();"
class="txtBox">
  <option value="">-- --Select-- --</option>
  <optgroup label="Popular Destinations">
    <option value="MA05110065">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="MA05110067">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="MA05110069">Singapore</option>
    <option value="MA05110001">Thailand</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Other Destinations">
    <option value="MA05110083">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="MA05110124">Albania</option>
    <option value="MA05110133">Algeria</option>
    <option value="MA05110186">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="MA05110103">Andorra</option>
    <option value="MA05110014">Angola</option>
    <option value="MA05110135">Anguilla (UK)</option>
    <option value="MA05110136">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="MA05110171">Argentina</option>
    <option value="MA05110206">Armenia</option>
    <option value="MA05110183">Venezuela</option>
    <option value="MA05110070">Vietnam</option>
    <option value="MA05110013">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="MA05110082">Yemen</option>
    <option value="MA05110027">Zambia</option>
    <option value="MA05110028">Zimbabwe</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

And this one for cboCity select option :

```html
<select name="cboCity" id="cboCity" onkeypress="return selectItem();" onkeyup="event.cancelbubble=true;return false;" onkeydown="return handleKey();" onfocus="activeList=this;this.enteredText='';" onchange="//hs.DropLocation();" onblur="hs.DropLocation();"
class="txtBox">
  <option value="">-- --Select-- --</option>
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="MA02022810">Ambarawa</option>
  <option value="MA09090008">Ambon</option>
  <option value="MA08090042">Anyer</option>
  <option value="MA02022861">Wonosobo</option>
  <option value="MA06060051">Yogyakarta</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the distinction between property and attribute. Browsers usually don't re-evaluate attributes when you change them in the DOM. In those cases, you would need to change the property behind that attribute on the DOM element.

In this case, you need to change the selected index. The select element has the `selectedIndex` property that you can change to the intended option which you can get through `option.index`:

```js
function setSelectedCountry(i){
    __utils__.echo("i :"+i);
    var opt = "//*[@id='cboCountry']/optgroup[2]/option["+i+"]";
    var select = document.getElementById('cboCountry');
    select.selectedIndex = __utils__.getElementByXPath(opt).index;
    select.onblur(); // or `onchange()`
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2226069) for more information on the option index.

---

`"//*[@id='cboCity']/option["+i+"]"` cannot work, because this expression will match options that are direct children of a `#cboCity` element, but you have an `optgroup` inbetween. Either use `"//*[@id='cboCity']//option["+i+"]"` or `"//*[@id='cboCity']/optgroup/option["+i+"]"`.

Comment: but for select option which has id = cboCity have no optgroup...
so this is should be run, but I got that error...
and when I try to 
return __utils__.getElementsByXPath("//*[@id='cboCity']/option["+i+"]").getAttribute("value");
that getAttribute evaluated with error...the casper said, type error undefined is no a function...how about this? what I have missed?

Comment: What `i` did you use? Also, I'm just guessing, since you haven't shown your markup.

Comment: i was used for iterator, it can be option (with optgroup => #cboCountry or without optgroup => #cboCity) iterator
I'll update my question to display you my markup

Comment: The markup looks fine. So, selecting the country works now, but selecting the city does not? Does the city select element depend on the country select element? If yes, then you need to wait until it's populated.

Comment: Ya city depend on country. I have made conditional wait for get the cities. It works fine if I only attempt to take those text, but problem happened when I try to pull the value, either it from city or country. And the returned city is correct. So I guess the were something wrong about xpath processing. It works fine if I use jQuery and css path...how that could be?

Comment: The error suggests that the element doesn't exist. Perhaps you're using an `i` that doesn't exist. XPath and CSS start counting positions from 1.