# How to select an option from dynamic drop down menu using CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html-select, casperjs

I am trying to select an option from a dropdown menu. 
It does not matter what option I choose as long as i choose one. 
I need to select the option so it opens up a new set of input boxes where I will edit what I need to -

Here is the HTML

```
<select style="" id="selectedAddressId" required="" class="has-validation 
  ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required 
  ng-touched" name="selectedAddressId" ng-model="addressChoice"
  default-option="Choose your address" 
  ng-options="(address.Text || address.text) for address in results">
    <option class="" value="" disabled="" selected="selected">Choose your address</option>
    <option value="object:348" label="2, Abbey Road, Nottingham">2, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:349" label="4, Abbey Road, Nottingham">4, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:350" label="6, Abbey Road, Nottingham">6, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:351" label="8, Abbey Road, Nottingham">8, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:352" label="10, Abbey Road, Nottingham">10, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:353" label="12, Abbey Road, Nottingham">12, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:354" label="14, Abbey Road, Nottingham">14, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:355" label="16, Abbey Road, Nottingham">16, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:356" label="18, Abbey Road, Nottingham">18, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:357" label="20, Abbey Road, Nottingham">20, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:358" label="22, Abbey Road, Nottingham">22, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:359" label="24, Abbey Road, Nottingham">24, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:360" label="26, Abbey Road, Nottingham">26, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:361" label="28, Abbey Road, Nottingham">28, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:362" label="30, Abbey Road, Nottingham">30, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:363" label="32, Abbey Road, Nottingham">32, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:364" label="34, Abbey Road, Nottingham">34, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:365" label="36, Abbey Road, Nottingham">36, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:366" label="38, Abbey Road, Nottingham">38, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:367" label="40, Abbey Road, Nottingham">40, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:368" label="42, Abbey Road, Nottingham">42, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:369" label="44, Abbey Road, Nottingham">44, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:370" label="46, Abbey Road, Nottingham">46, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:371" label="48, Abbey Road, Nottingham">48, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:372" label="50, Abbey Road, Nottingham">50, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
    <option value="object:373" label="52, Abbey Road, Nottingham">52, Abbey Road, Nottingham</option>
  </select>
```

How can i do this in CasperJS? 
I have tried this following piece of code, but unfortunately it does click the box button does not select an option

```
casper.then(function(){
  this.fillSelectors('#identification', {
    '#selectedAddressId': 'option:nth-child(3)'
  }, false);
});
```

Comment: well @ArtjomB.why no expand on your comment all i need to do is select at least the 2nd option down it cannot be specific as the options change each time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select an option with CasperJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136361/how-to-select-an-option-with-casperjs)